# Como converter tipo Time em String?

Tags: java, data, servlet, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho um campo `horaConsulta` e não consigo converter ele em `String`

**DAO**

`stmt.setTime(4, new java.sql.Time(consulta.getHoraConsulta().getTime()));`

**Servlet**

`Time horaConsulta = converterTime(request.getParameter("horaConsulta").replace(":", ":"));`

Comment: Poste o código de `converterTime` para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Por que o `replace(":",":")`? Você quer o seu `Time` em `String`? O `.toString()` não serve?

Answer (score 4):

Se entendi sua pergunta é transforma Dates e Times em e vice-versa Strings, uma forma fácil de fazer é usando SimpleDateFormat, passando uma string com formato de hora. O inverso também é possível.

Exemplo

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); //Hora, minuto, segundo.
formatter.format(new Date()); // Deverá mostrar hora atual em string
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/mm/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
Date date = parser.parse("21/02/1987 02:02:00"); // Deverá transformar a string em Date se a data estiver no padrão
```

[Como converter data em string e em data de novo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492419/how-to-convert-date-to-string-and-to-date-again)

[Documentação da Classe SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

[Documentação da Classe DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Comment: O objeto dele é um Time e não um Date.

Comment: Vi que tinha .getHoraConsulta().getTime(), suspeitei que fosse uso de Date(a API antiga) em java. O getTime() do date vai retornar um long, pode ser utilizado no construtor de java.sql.Time, que segundo a javadoc, é um wrapper fino usado pela api jdbc, para valores SQL TIME em millisegundos. Então é natural usar o Objeto como Date, depois transformá-lo em Time.

Comment: Hmmm verdade. Boa observação.